# Model selection for penalized regression

Tags: regression, regularization

I was wondering if for penalised regression like lasso, elastic net, ridge when using Aic, Bic or simply CV does one include the penalty term in the likelihood in those three? E.g for the lasso RSS + lamba*l1penalty.  I saw both actually. Some authors seem to include it. So I m a bit confused. Would appreciate any help!